# Targeting a different php version with Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

Is there a way to do a Composer build with a php version different from what is installed locally?

My use case is that I have a development container using php56 which lives on a host that has php54.  The two environments have a shared folder where the project files live, and I do my builds from an IDE living on the host machine (which uses 5.4).

In a perfect world, I would just upgrade my host to 5.6, but I work on some projects with the lower version.

Comment: So you want to do a composer install with php 5.6 on a php 5.4 host?

Comment: @Mitchell Olsthoorn: Yessir.

Comment: For what it's worth - I installed php56 temporarily to work around the issue, but it would be nice to be able to do builds targeting a specific php version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been accomplishing this using [Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/composer/composer/):

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/app composer/composer update
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can change that because composer uses the php version that composer is run with, so there are only a few options

- Install the required php version as extra installation (as you already did)
- Change the source of composer where the version is taken from the php environment (not really a good idea)
- Maybe installing the dependencies from your development box, because you said that you had a shared folder between the systems

The last option is the most promising in my opinion because linux has very nice support for hosting multiple versions of php with phpenv

Sorry I couldn't give you a real solution